# android spell corrector

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, spell-checking, prediction

Is there a way to access android's spell correcting facilities? For example when sending a text on an android phone a list of words appears that may be the next most likely word that is men't. For example if a user input the string circal then I would have access to a list of words such as circle, circus ...

Is there a facility/ class I can use that I can use to access these words if I provide a string? I have heard that using an autoComplete textview may do it but can't figure out how? or will a whole new spelling corrector need to be created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Android's [Spelling Checker Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html).

The best method of integrating with the framework will vary depending on your specific needs, but there are plenty of examples in the documentation.